# Category of Post created by Strapi cannot be retrieved by GraphQL of Gatsby.js. However, it is displayed in GraphiQL of Gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, strapi

Category of Post created by Strapi cannot be retrieved by GraphQL of Gatsby.js.
However, it is displayed in GraphiQL of Gatsby.js.

I can call and display all but categories.

I am calling it as follows.

{categories.name}、{category.slug}
I can't get these.

gatsby-config.js

```
     {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
      options: {
        apiURL:`http://localhost:1337`,
        collectionTypes: [`post`,`category`],
      },
    },
```

index.js

```
    const IndexPage = (props) => {
  const posts = props.data.allStrapiPost.nodes;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Helmet>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="xxxxxxx"
        />
      </Helmet>
      <div className={styles.container}>
 
      <PostList posts={posts}  />
      
      </div>


    </Layout>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allStrapiPost {
      nodes {
        title
        slug
        content
        thumbnail
        published_at (formatString: "YYYY.MM.DD hh:mm")
        categories {
          name
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
 
`;

export default IndexPage;
```

PostList.js

```
import React from "react"
import PostCell from "./PostCell";
import * as styles from "./PostList.module.css"

const PostList = props => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.posts.map(post => {
        return (
          <div className={styles.container}>
        <PostCell post={post} key={post.slug}  />
        </div>
        )

      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default PostList
```

PostCell.js

```
    import React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import * as styles from "./PostCell.module.css";
import {Row,Col,Card,Button,container,OverlayTrigger} from 'react-bootstrap'


const PostCell = (props) => {
  const { title, content, categories, published_at, slug, thumbnail } = props.post;
  const plainContent = (content || "").replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
  return (


      <Card className={styles.container} >
            <Link to={`/posts/${slug}` } className={styles.link}>

          <Card.Img className="m-0" variant="top" src={thumbnail} alt={title} style={{width:`351px`,height:`160px`}}></Card.Img>
          <Card.Body  className={styles.cardContents} >
<Card.Title  variant="light" className={styles.cardTitle}>     {title}
</Card.Title>

<div className={styles.footer}>

<Link to={`/category/${categories.slug}`} >
<Button className="categoryButton" variant='primary' style={{padding:`5px`,fontSize:`10px`}}>{categories.name}</Button>
</Link>
<Card.Footer >{published_at}</Card.Footer>
</div>

        </Card.Body>
        </Link>

      </Card>
      

    

    

    
  );
};

export default PostCell;
```

[image]

The strapi role has been set.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to see the categories in GraphiQL and not display them, your issue is in the view and how are you treating the data. In this case, (after the typical editions), `categories` is an array as `posts` are so unless you loop through them, you won't be able to display them.

Do something like:

```
    import React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import * as styles from "./PostCell.module.css";
import {Row,Col,Card,Button,container,OverlayTrigger} from 'react-bootstrap'


const PostCell = (props) => {
  const { title, content, categories, published_at, slug, thumbnail } = props.post;
  const plainContent = (content || "").replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
  return (


      <Card className={styles.container} >
            <Link to={`/posts/${slug}` } className={styles.link}>

          <Card.Img className="m-0" variant="top" src={thumbnail} alt={title} style={{width:`351px`,height:`160px`}}></Card.Img>
          <Card.Body  className={styles.cardContents} >
<Card.Title  variant="light" className={styles.cardTitle}>     {title}
</Card.Title>

<div className={styles.footer}>

<Link to={`/category/${categories.slug}`} >
{categories.map(category=>{
   return <Button className="categoryButton" variant='primary' style={{padding:`5px`,fontSize:`10px`}}>{category.name}</Button>
})}
</Link>
<Card.Footer >{published_at}</Card.Footer>
</div>

        </Card.Body>
        </Link>

      </Card>
```

The key part is:

```
{categories.map(category=>{
   return <Button className="categoryButton" variant='primary' style={{padding:`5px`,fontSize:`10px`}}>{category.name}</Button>
})}
```

Comment: I added PostList.I hope look you

Comment: Your questions are a mess. What's `PostContents` and `PostCell` now?

Comment: sorry, I repaired it

Comment: You need to loop through categories.

Comment: Thank you. Where should I loop it?

Comment: You just need to copy-paste the snippet, it's all in the answer. In the `PostCell` or in a new component, as you wish